# Error cannot find -lz building MariaDB on a debian based container

Tags: docker, mariadb

I'm trying to build MariaDB on a Debian based container. But it cannot find a `z` library.

Here is the container image script:

```
FROM debian

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y libncurses-dev
RUN apt-get install -y build-essential;
RUN apt-get install -y cmake;

COPY mariadb-10.1.18.tar.gz /usr/bin/
WORKDIR /usr/bin/
RUN gzip -d mariadb-10.1.18.tar.gz
RUN tar -xvf mariadb-10.1.18.tar
RUN ln -s mariadb-10.1.18 mariadb

WORKDIR /usr/bin/mariadb/
RUN mkdir install; mkdir install/data; mkdir install/var; mkdir install/etc; mkdir install/tmp

RUN cd /usr/bin/mariadb/;
RUN rm -f CMakeCache.txt;
RUN cmake \
  -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/bin/mariadb/install \
  -DWITH_INNOBASE_STORAGE_ENGINE=1 \
  -DMYSQL_DATADIR=/usr/bin/mariadb/install/data \
  -DDOWNLOAD_BOOST=1 \
  -DWITH_BOOST=/usr/bin/mariadb/install/boost \
  -DMYSQL_UNIX_ADDR=/usr/bin/mariadb/install/tmp/mariadb.sock
```

And the console output:

```
[ 77%] Building CXX object storage/tokudb/PerconaFT/ft/CMakeFiles/ft.dir/log_print.cc.o
Linking CXX shared library libft.so
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lz
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
storage/tokudb/PerconaFT/ft/CMakeFiles/ft.dir/build.make:1323: recipe for target 'storage/tokudb/PerconaFT/ft/libft.so' failed
make[2]: *** [storage/tokudb/PerconaFT/ft/libft.so] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:3438: recipe for target 'storage/tokudb/PerconaFT/ft/CMakeFiles/ft.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [storage/tokudb/PerconaFT/ft/CMakeFiles/ft.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:147: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
The command '/bin/sh -c make' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

Answer (score 1):

either change the container script and specify CMake parameter `-DWITH_ZLIB=bundled` to use zlib sources in extra/zlib or install zlib by `apt-get install zlib-devel`

Comment: I had tried adding this statement `RUN apt-get install -y zlib-devel` which gave me the following error `E: Unable to locate package zlib-devel`. And same with `zlib-dev` and `zlib`.

Comment: I then tried to use the `-DWITH_ZLIB=bundled` option instead. But it gave me the same error: `Linking CXX shared library libft.so
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lz`.

Comment: You have run my Dockerfile on your machine ? to see if you get the same message...

Comment: Just build without TokuDB.  pass -DTOKUDB_OK=0 to cmake parameters.

Comment: I had to install this one package `apt-get install -y zlib1g-dev` to have it work.